# Transcompiling to bare bones C?

Tags: compiler-construction, go

While watching some FOSDEM'14 presentations I found [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qe8Dq7V3hXY) being particularly interesting. It is about the Go programming language and how it gives access to compiler's internal through packages. So basically you can write a program in Go that gets AST (abstract syntax tree) or more low level SSA (single static assignment) and analyze it, or transforms it into something else (like transcompiling it to JavaScript for example). I find it very interesting. I can remember a few other languages that do it: Vala ([JavaScript transcompiler](http://lethalman.hostei.com/maja/index.html)) and Boo [another JavaScript transcompiler](https://github.com/drslump/BooJS). Some languages provide parsing code to AST as a separate library, like [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) for C/C++/ObjC, [ASIS](https://www.adacore.com/asis) for Ada, or [CodeTools](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Codetools) for Free Pascal, but it is not quite the same.

I'm thinking of making a Go transcompiler to bare bones C/C++ (to make it be more suitable for os development and just for the fun of it), do you think it is a good idea? Is there any other language that may be more easy to transcompile to bare bones C/C++?

Comment: You can consider LLVM or C--, both are languages designed for this very purpose. Using some sort of Forth-dialect is also good.

Comment: I don't think trying to compile Go into "bare bones C/C++" is a good idea. Correction, I think it doesn't even make sense. Either you stick with the Go runtime and just get a roundabout way of compiling Go code (Go -> C++ -> binary instead of Go -> binary) that isn't any more suited for OS development, or you strip Go of everything that requires a runtime and wind up with half a language that isn't really useful for anything, not to mention breaking every interesting Go program ever.

Comment: What problem does compiling to C instead of machine language solve?

Answer (score 1):

The problem that occurs to me is garbage collection - if you've transcompiled to pure C/C++ then you either have to automatically insert the correct free() calls or your code will leak memory all over the place.